# How ro use onclick event for mobile device?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-handling

i am currently working on project
i have using onclik method for search data on my chat app.
like below :-

```
    <div className="userChat"  id="myform" onClick={handleSelect} >
      <img src={user.photoURL} alt="" />
      <div className="userChatInfo">
        <span>{user.displayName}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

i want to use this line of code for mobile devices (screen touch) how can i do that?

Comment: Investigate [Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events) and perhaps implement something like [React Touch Events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-touch-events)

Answer (score 0):

there are events like ontouchstart or ontouched that do what you want

```
<div className="userChat"  id="myform" ontouchstart={handleSelect} ontouchend={handleSelect} >
  <img src={user.photoURL} alt="" />
  <div className="userChatInfo">
    <span>{user.displayName}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

read about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events